# How can I get the pixel index of the caret in a TinyMCE editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I am trying to add a dropdown at the caret but the caretPosition.top is too small a number:

```
            function updateDropdownPosition() {
                const editorElement = editor.editorContainer;
                const editorRect = editorElement.getBoundingClientRect();

                // Calculate the top and left coordinates relative to the page
                const editorTop = editorRect.top + window.scrollY;
                const editorLeft = editorRect.left + window.scrollX;

                // Calculate the caret position within the editor
                const caretPosition = editor.selection.getRng().getClientRects()[0];
                const topWithCaret = editorTop + caretPosition.top;
                const leftWithCaret = editorLeft + caretPosition.left;

                $dropdownContainer.css({
                    top: topWithCaret + 'px', left: leftWithCaret + 'px',
                });
            }
```